# Any auto grading site that supports all-testcases-in-one-file (and/or in github)?

Tags: resource-request, auto-graders, unit-testing

I use repl.it,  and one problem i note, is that each new test case has to be added by many gui-web clicks.
it is both slow and annoying, and makes it harder to :
1) send to other teacher to review the testcase
2) store the assignment in github ( for backup/ development/review)
3) see all tests cases at once
4) transfer info between sites ( if a better site is found, i want to transfer all the assignments data inc. testcases easily to the better site).

Saw in another SE-CS-educators thread, STEPIK  site and in some other thread VPL for Moodle was suggested. 
How many have used VPL-Moodle for K12 ?   and STEPIK ?    (  grades 10-12) 
Are there any *other* autograder sites, that support one-file-that-contains-all-test-cases  ?

Comment: This is more of a technology question than a teaching question.

Comment: Auto grader sites could come and go. How to evaluate and select one could be useful. With enough rep, soon available, experience could be shared in chatroom.

Answer (score 4):

At the TU Delft we've developed [WebLab](https://weblab.tudelft.nl/), which is used in various CS related courses. It has support for programming assignments, for which students code their solutions in a web-editor, and run their code against their own tests, and the spec-tests.

- Grades are automatically calculated based on the number of succeeding specification tests.

  - As a `Course Manager`, you specify the `spec-tests` by writing JUnit tests in a single file (in case of Java).
  - Students can run the spec-tests, and the UI will only reveal the test score to students, while managers have access to the complete output of the program.
- Optionally, the automatically computed grade can be combined with `manual grading components` (e.g. a checklist).

  - It provides an interface to walk over all submissions.
  - Each `Grader` can be assigned their share of the submissions to be graded

Other types of assignments supported include: `Essay questions` (manual grading), `Multiple Choice questions` (automatic grading), `File Submission questions` (manual grading) and `Peer Review questions` (manual grading). For programming assignments it has built-in support for Java, Scala, Python and C, but this can be extended with any language for which you can provide a Docker image that handles input/outputs results in WebLab format.

You can sign up and enrol for [this demo-course](https://weblab.tudelft.nl/wl101/demo-assignment-types/) to get an idea of its interface as a student.
If you're interested, we can set up a demo course for you by [submitting a course request](https://weblab.tudelft.nl/about) (sign in first).

Comment: Is this available for CS teachers free of charge?